# What does size parameter in gensim doc2vec represent

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

In [`doc2vec` function](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html), there is a parameter called `size`.

I understand that, `size` is the dimension of output vector, and if `size=400` it will capture the content better than if `size=100`.

However, I do not understand, what does `size` stand for? Does it mean how far Doc2Vec will lookup from a word, to predict the next word? Or what does it mean?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

`size` is the number of dimensions in the created vectors. So `size=100` means each document (actually, document-tag) receives a 100-dimensional vector from training.

More dimensions aren't always better: they mean slower training and a larger model. And if you're working on a small dataset, too many dimensions risks overfitting – preventing the model from representing generalizable patterns in the data.